# Visualización gráfica de tiempos

Tags: python, matplotlib, diccionarios, spyder

Necesito implementar una función que genere una gráfica en la que se representan los tiempos medidos en una serie de algoritmos (eje y) para distintas tallas (eje x). Debe generar una gráfica de puntos (sin unir cada valor representado mediante líneas).

`xvalor`: lista con las tallas para las que se han realizado medidas

`yvalor`: diccionario que contiene como clave de cada entrada el nombre e instancia del algoritmo medido y como valor una lista (del mismo tamaño que `xdata`) con los tiempos medidos.

```
def plot_data(xvalor, yvalor):
    for yvalor in xvalor : 
        plt.plot(xvalor,yvalor)     
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás iterando mal, debes iterar sobre los items del diccionario, cada clave (algoritmo) es una linea (que podemos usar como legenda) y su valor son los valores para el eje `y` de ese algoritmo. Los valores para el eje `x` son los mismos para todos.

Por otro lado, solo debes llamar a `plot` cuando tengas todas las lineas creadas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_data(xvalor, yvalor):
    for algoritmo, tiempos in yvalor.items():
        plt.plot(xvalor, tiempos, ".", label=algoritmo)  
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.xlabel('Tallas')
    plt.ylabel('Tiempo')
    plt.show()
```

---

```
xvalor = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
yvalor = {"Foo": [12.3, 15.4, 17.2, 17.9, 18.0, 19.2],
          "Bar": [14.2, 14.5, 15.9, 16.7, 19.3, 20.1]}

plot_data(xvalor, yvalor)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ```plt.legend(loc="upper left") ``` para que se utiliza

Comment: Para colocar la leyenda en la equina superior izquierda. Puedes colocarla dónde quieras, o no colocarla...